# Echange Managed API: How do I select a category for an appointment

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

In Outlook you can assign a category to an appointment. There are categories like Personell or Business etc.
I need to assign a category to an appointment, via Exchange Managed API. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8):

You can do that by adding entries to the Categories collection:

```
appointment.Categories.Add("Business");
```

The colors are configured via the Master Category list.
See my article [Working with the Master Category List–EWS edition](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/07/28/Working-with-the-Master-Category-List%E2%80%93EWS-edition.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I tried applying Krause's answer to messages (not appointments) and found out I also needed to update the message:

```
message.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```

(or a different ConflictResolutionMode)

Just FYI for anyone else who stumbles here and wonders why a message (or presumably even an appointment) doesn't get updated after adding a category. :)